# deducing a tuple's types

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++14, template-argument-deduction

I have code something like this:

```
template <typename T>
inline typename ::std::enable_if<
  is_std_tuple<T>{},
  T
>::type
get()
{
  // pull tuple's elements from somewhere
}
```

In order to deduce the template type parameters the tuple was instantiated with, I did this casting:

```
static_cast<T*>(nullptr)
```

and pass this as a parameter to a function

```
template <typename ...A>
void deduce_tuple(::std::tuple<A...>* const);
```

Am I committing UB? Is there a better way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with casting a null pointer to a type, as long as you don't dereference it. What all are you trying to do?

Comment: I just need the `A...` parameter pack in the function and don't know how to get it otherwise, other than with the indices trick and `::std::tuple_element<>`

Comment: One benefit of sticking with `tuple_size` and `tuple_element` is that your code works with `std::pair` and `std::array` too for free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The imperfection here is that we cannot partially specialize function templates. Your way is fine, since we're not dereferencing the null pointer; I'd prefer using a designated tag:

```
template <typename...> struct deduction_tag {};

template <typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> get(deduction_tag<std::tuple<Ts...>>) {
    // […]
}
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_std_tuple<T>{}, T> get() {
    return get(deduction_tag<T>{});
}
```